# How to change Microsoft Word Heading style

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

For example, Heading 1 is automatically typeset as `Chapter 1: Chapter 1 Title.` I would like to change this to `Chapter 1 - Chapter 1 Title` however. How can I achieve this? I'm using Word 2013.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing but about how to use a specific software application. There are other forums for this.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're searching Google using the word style, I don't think you'll find your answer. Microsoft uses Style to mean something different than what you're asking (since you want to change the text, not the font, size, or color). You will have better responses if you look up heading templates, most likely. [Here](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/content.php?pid=245394&sid=2027134) is a page that might help, though.

Comment: Press the F1 to bring up help and type 'change heading style' or something similar into the search box.

Comment: Closed, this is off-topic here. Superuser has a [microsoft-word-2013](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2013) tag, you might consider searching those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "Chapter 1 - ..." portion, you'd want to right-click the Heading style, then click **Format** >> **Numbering** >> **Define New Number Format**, and then set the **Number format** as "Number 1 - "

For the "chapter title" portion, you'd want to define a "SUBJECT" field code (say) in the header, and then refer to that field code in the document.

1. So in the header, go **Header & Footer Tools** >> **Quick Parts** >> **Field**
2. Under **Field Names**, choose **Subject**, then type the **New subject** text that should appear (i.e., the chapter title).
3. At this point, you can use **[Alt + F9]** to toggle the field.
4. Exit out of the header, and on a line in your document, go **Insert** >> **Quick Parts** >> **Document Property** >> **Subject**.
5. This will place an instance of the resulting field, which (when selected) will have a **Subject** tag.
6. For the **Subject** tag that you just placed, assign the Header style, such that the result is "Chapter 1 - Chapter 1 Title"

Unfortunately, Word doesn't let you simply paste that **Subject** tag into the **Number format** field (it turns into plain text, stipping off the field code). However, if you create a blank document with the basic fields that you need, then you can use that as a template for each new chapter you create.

When working with fields, if a field isn't updating, then you can typically right-click and choose **Update Field** to force the update.

As an alternative to clicking through the **Quick Parts** menu, the keyboard shortcut is **[Alt + i + f]** (i.e., Alt insert field, which is the old school menu shortcut that still works).